# How to copy my Windows installation to new disk (with some conditions)

Tags: windows, hard-drive

How can I copy my entire Windows 7 hard disk to another? The main point is to copy all files in the NTFS partition and their respective attributes/permissions.

The caveats are:

- the source disk doesn't boot, but is accessible in an external drive
- the source disk and destination disk are of different sizes
- I don't have another working Windows installation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using a [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org) bootable CD. You will need to clone your entire drive to a Clonezilla image.

However, as you said, your disk drives have different sizes. You must be careful with that because a bigger image will not be recovered to a smaller disk. You can solve this by resizing your old disk before creating your Clonezilla image. To do that I, recommend you use [Easesus](http://www.easesus.com) partition manager.

Maybe you can find more information in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/310448/copying-windows-installation-to-another-hd/310449#310449) post.